# Minimizing a function of more than a hundred variables on matlab

Tags: matlab, minimization, bigdata

I'm trying to minimize a function of ~ 120 variables (I'm estimating parameters via maximum likelihood) with the function `fminunc` of Matlab, but the iteration steps are really slow. What are the ways I can accelerate this process?

The function is nonlinear and comprises a lot of summations.

I'm thinking about vectorizing as much as possible the function definition and maybe providing the gradient function to Matlab, but apart from these solutions I don't know what other possibilities are available.

Comment: Often, when standard algorithms are slow, you need to write the optimization strategy yourself and optimize it for your specific problem

Comment: Do you have constraints in your problem, or can you think of even some logical bounds for your variables ? In that case `fmincon` may work out better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the minimization was slow because I implemented the sums in the function with `for` loops. Now instead, I vectorized the problem as much as possible, using matrix multiplications and vectors as often as I could and the optimization by `fminunc` was much faster.